# How to generate microsoft secret from code and uri

Tags: javascript, multi-factor-authentication

I have a qr barcode with the option to manually add to an authenticator app with a code and uri. Is there some way I can generate this secret programmatically using node. My intention is to generate token so I can log into Microsoft azure account to an application I want to test with cypress.